# Stuck with broken library for TradeSatoshi exchange

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a trading robot for TradeSatoshi-exchange. I'm using this small library https://github.com/ShuffleDATMT/TradeSatoshiAPI

It's probably a quick simple fix, but I'm new to C# so I'm asking for some help here.

I am getting a parsing error when trying to fetch my balance from TradeSatoshi API. Others are writing that they're getting the loginscreen instead of the jason string. So there's something wrong in these attached methods.

The code that I use to call it is just the demo code in the TesterProject but with my key and secret filled in.

This is the error I get.
JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Which probably is explained by getting the wrong format/page back.

If anyone could help out I would be really grateful!.

```
public static async Task<GetBalanceReturn> GetBalance(string Currency)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string uri = "https://tradesatoshi.com/api/private/getbalance";
                string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                JObject post_params = new JObject();
                post_params.Add("Currency", Currency);
                string signature = GetSignature(uri, nonce, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post_params)).Result;
                string authenticationString = "Basic " + GlobalSettings.API_Key + ":" + signature + ":" + nonce;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authentication", authenticationString);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetBalanceReturn>(await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post_params), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            catch(Exception e) { throw e; };
        }
    }
```

And here is the method creating the HMAC signature.

```
    private static Task<string> GetSignature(string uri, string nonce, string post_params = null)
    {
        string signature = "";
        if (post_params != null)
        {
            post_params = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_params));
            signature = GlobalSettings.API_Key + "POST" + uri + nonce + post_params;
        }
        else
        {
            signature = GlobalSettings.API_Key + "POST" + uri + nonce;
        }
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
        using (HMACSHA512 _object = new HMACSHA512(GlobalSettings.Secret_Key))
        {
            byte[] hashmessage = _object.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            return Task.FromResult(Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest breaking out each the of the Json call individual statements and put debugger messages to each one so you can see which Json call is actually failing.  That might help identify the problem.  There's several "reader" calls in that code itself.

Comment: They seem to be fine, it's probably something with the authentication, that fails since I don't get the json data back.. I get a webpage back if I fetch the data into a result variable.

Answer (score 0):

The TradeSatoshi API is broken for the getbalance endpoint (for some reason the service always produces the error "Somthing went wrong, please try again later.").  The getbalances endpoint does work, so you can filter the results from getbalances to retrieve the balance for a particular currency.  I use something similar to the code shown below and it works for most private API calls to tradesatoshi.

If you need help with private or public calls to tradesatoshi using C#, I have an unfinished (as of yet) client I can post to github.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TradeSatoshi.Console
{
    public class TradeSatoshiResponse<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "success")]
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A <see cref="BalanceInfo"/> instance is one returned from the  https://tradesatoshi.com/api/private/getbalance URI
    /// </summary>
    public class BalanceInfo
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CurrencyLong")]
        public string CurrencyLongName { get; set; }
        public decimal Available { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public decimal HeldForTrades { get; set; }
        public decimal Unconfirmed { get; set; }
        public decimal PendingWithdraw { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Currency: {Currency}, CurrencyLongName: {CurrencyLongName}, Available: {Available}, Total: {Total}, HeldForTrades: {HeldForTrades}, Unconfirmed: {Unconfirmed}, PendingWithdrawl: {PendingWithdraw}, Address: {Address}";
        }
    }

    class StackExchangeQuestion
    {
        private const string PUBLIC_API_KEY = "your public key";
        private const string PRIVATE_API_KEY = "your private key";

        public static async Task GetBalance(string Currency)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var uri = new Uri("https://tradesatoshi.com/api/private/getbalances");
                    string nonce = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();
                    JObject post_params = new JObject();
                    post_params.Add("Currency", "BTC"); //not needed for getbalances, but I left it in here to show how post params would be used
                    string serializedParms = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post_params);
                    string signature = CreateSignature(uri, serializedParms, nonce);
                    var content = CreateHttpContent(serializedParms);
                    var request = CreateHttpRequestMessage(uri, signature, content, nonce);
                    var result = await client.SendAsync(request).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeSatoshiResponse<IList<BalanceInfo>>>(result);
                    var balance = ((IList<BalanceInfo>)response.Data).Single(x => x.Currency == "BTC");
                    System.Console.WriteLine(balance);

                }
                catch (Exception e) { throw e; };
            }
        }

        public static string CreateSignature(Uri uri, string parameters, string nonce)
        {
            //SIGNATURE: API_KEY + "POST" + URI + NONCE + POST_PARAMS(signed by secret key according to HMAC - SHA512 method.)
            string endpoint = WebUtility.UrlEncode(uri.ToString()).ToLower();
            parameters = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters ?? ""));
            var signature = $"{PUBLIC_API_KEY}POST{endpoint}{nonce}{parameters}";
            using (var hashAlgo = new HMACSHA512(Convert.FromBase64String(PRIVATE_API_KEY)))
            {
                var signedBytes = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature));
                return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
            }
        }

        public static HttpContent CreateHttpContent(string jsonParams)
        {
            return new StringContent(jsonParams ?? "", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }

        public static HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequestMessage(Uri uri, string signature, HttpContent content, string nonce)
        {
            var header = $"Basic {PUBLIC_API_KEY}:{signature}:{nonce}";
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
            message.Content = content;
            return message;
        }

    }
}
```